# Get value of date filter web part

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a date filter web part and a list web part in a page.

I want to get the value of date filter web part using javascript or jQuery. I am using the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {   
 var x=document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl41_g_ed4beb82_8f7e_4389_bb35_a44188462aab_DateFilterPicker_DateFilterPickerDate");
     alert(x.innerHTML);  
  } 
});
</script>
```

where `ctl00_ctl41_g_ed4beb82_8f7e_4389_bb35_a44188462aab_DateFilterPicker_DateFilterPickerDate` is the id of the date filter web part.

In alert box, it shows blank.

What changes has to be made to get the value of date filter web part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@vikash As it is an `input` element of type `text`

you can get the value of it by using value property `x.value`